# find-the-longest-semi-repetitive-substring Leetcode Question

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def longestSemiRepetitiveSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        trench=0
        max_length=0
        mapi=[]
        repe=False
        scope=0
        troll=0
        while trench<len(s):
            if s[trench] in mapi and repe==False:
                repe=True
                troll=trench
            elif s[trench] in mapi and repe==True:
                repe=False
                mapi=[s[trench]]
                if (trench-scope)>max_length:
                    max_length=trench-scope
                scope=troll
            if trench==len(s)-1 and repe==True:
                if (trench-scope)>max_length:
                    max_length=trench-scope+1
            mapi.append(s[trench])
            trench+=1
        if max_length==0 and len(s)>0:
            return len(s)
        return max_length
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-longest-semi-repetitive-substring/description/
I took wrong answer when implement to this code.How can i solve the wrong answer problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.